# How to obfuscate a certain class on android?

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am developing an Android application that will released soon. Some of my classes contain a very sensitive information. By using Proguard, I obfuscated the whole source code, but I met a large number of bugs later. Now I am planning to obfuscate my code one by one. How to obfuscate a certain class and skip most of the class?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458909/how-to-use-java-annotations-to-guide-androids-proguard

Comment: You understand this doesn't make any sense, because .class and .dex files are different. A dex is all the classes in one file, it's impossible to just change one class, because you'd also have to change all the references to it elsewhere in your code.

Comment: My explanation may a bit weird. I intend to obfuscate a class, and find some bugs that might occur. If it safe, I will include another class in the next obfuscation process, and find some bugs again. I will repeat this step until I feel it safe to release it to the market.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble with obfuscated Java-Classes. In fact yGuard (yGuard != proguard, I know) generated *.class files, which where unable to convert to *.dex.

If your code contains sensitive Data, it sounds like some kind of "[security by obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)". Maybe you should store sensitive data not inside your *.class file rather than an encrypted property-file.

Comment: But then, one could decompile the .class files and get the decryption key. Doesn't matter what you do, if you rely in security by obscurity, there will always be a way to break it.

Comment: Jes, for sure. Thats why I mentioned not to store secrets in *.class-files. If you store a pre-shared secret within your code, it can be stolen.

Comment: Yes, I will consider your advice @ckuetbach. But I still need to obfuscate the code. I know it won't help much from a super genius hacker. But it should prevent any obvious attempt of reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

If you want to make obfuscation process in particular class you can use following line of code.

Syntax:

```
-keep public class yourPackageName.youClassname  { *; }
```

Example:

-keep public class com.facebook.katana.MainClass { *; }