# How do I configure Proguard with Android so it doesn't remove event handler methods referenced only in XML layouts?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, proguard

I've a number of activities where the handler method to be executed when the user taps certain UI elements is being stripped by Proguard because it can't see that it's being used.

What's the best solution to this?

- Turn off the code shrink feature in proguard (not ideal as it is beneficial in many areas)
- Is there a way to annotate methods I want it to leave in?
- How can I tweak a proguard config to never remove methods that start with "on"?

I tried adding this line (i.e. don't trim methods inheriting from my sublass of the Activity object) but it didn't have the desired effect. I assume it applies to the classes, but not their methods.

```
-keep public class * extends com.myapp.CustomActivity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each method you want to maintain add another line to the proguard file:

-keepclassmembers class * {
 public void exampleMethodName1(android.view.View);
 public void exampleMethodName2(android.view.View);
...
}

You can find this topic addressed at: [Proguard and reflection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447145/proguard-and-reflection-in-android-solved)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I added this and all is good: -keepclassmembers class * { public void on*(android.view.View); }