# Reflection methods are not working when used proguard for android application

Tags: android, reflection, proguard, telephony

I am facing a problem when i use proguard for application having used telephonyservice apis using reflection in android.

I have defined a package com.android.internal.telephony and there i have copied ITelephony.aidl file.

Here is the snippet of the code where i am using the methods of telephony using reflection.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = 
     (com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

    if(buttonInAction == acceptButton){
       Log.v(TAG, "Answering the call");
       telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
       finish();
    }
    else{
       Log.v(TAG, "Rejecting the call");
       telephonyService.endCall();
       finish();
    }
```

Now without proguard i am able to use this apis, but when i use proguard for compliling, it gives classcastexception. I know i need to add something in proguard.cfg file and i also tried several things like -dontshrink -dontoptimize, but still it did not work.

Please let me know if i am missing something which needs to be added in that file or any other solution to this problem.
Thanks
Nawab

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proguard and reflection in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447145/proguard-and-reflection-in-android)

Comment: I already looked at it but did not help me much.

Comment: I think i have found the answer....i used the option -keeppackagenames and it is working. I am still verifying it. Will post if it is the correct solution of this problem.

Comment: Yeah it had worked...:)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This solves issue:

```
-keep class com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony { *; }
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, i faced a problem when i applied this fix initially because i wasn't paying attention, I added the line but forgot to add the file to the build.cradle. it should be added like this:::::       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-project.txt'::::::

Comment: not work ,it complains SecurityException: null from uid 10320 not allowed to perform CALL_PHONE