# ProGuard java and reflection

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

I obfuscate my jar application with proguard. When i run the program I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflec
t.ParameterizedType
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.bridge.dao.HibernateDAO.HibernateGenericDAO.
<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.bridge.dao.HibernateDAO.HibernateDBSynchroni
zerDAO.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
rce)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at     gr.analysis.synchronizer.bridge.dao.HibernateDAO.HibernateBridgeDAOFactory.instantiateDAO(Unknown Source)
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.bridge.dao.HibernateDAO.HibernateBridgeDAOFactory.getDBSynchronizerDAO(Unknown Source)
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.forms.synchronizer.SynchronizersDialog.initSynchronizers(Unknown Source)
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.forms.synchronizer.SynchronizersDialog.perform(Unknown Source)
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.forms.synchronizer.SynchronizersDialog.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at gr.analysis.synchronizer.forms.synchronizer.SynchronizersDialog$13$1.
run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR [Performer] (?:?) - java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not instantiate DAO: class     gr.analysis.synchronizer.bridge.dao.HibernateDAO.HibernateDBSynchronizerDAO
```

I use hibernate with annotations and dao pattern

the config of proguard is:

```
-dontnote
-verbose
-printmapping out.map

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepdirectories

# The main entry points.

-keep public class gr.analysis.synchronizer.ApplicationSupport {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}


-keep class  gr.analysis.synchronizer.**{*; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is proguard + java reflection, e.g. Class.forName("com.example.class").getInstance().

Also applicable for non-android java projects, see: [Proguard and Reflection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447145/proguard-and-reflection-in-android)