# proguard obfuscation in android missing methods and classes

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate my application with proGuard and getting these errors:

```
Could not find class 'android.hardware.ConsumerIrManager', referenced from method com.g.b.d
```

I've found the class that uses it and set ProGuard to -keep it, but it remains.

Another issue is getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class com.path.to.not.obfuscated.location]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
```

my proguard-properties contains this:

```
-libraryjars /mnt/storage/bin/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar    

-keep public class * extends com.path.to.not.obfuscated.location

-keepclassmembers public class * extends com.path.to.not.obfuscated.location{
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

I thought the first line will handle the android.hardWare.ConsumerIrManager issue and the other will deal with the reflection like in this question: [Proguard and reflection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447145/proguard-and-reflection-in-android) but it didnt help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error.
I tryied un-obfuscate the class i entered as parameter in `getConstructor()`, but what i accualy needed to do is to un-obfuscate the class `getConstructor()` is being called on.

Answer (score 0):

if the "com.path.to.not.obfuscated.location" is in a .jar,
in your proguard.cfg file ,you must add the below line like this:

```
-libraryjars /libs/the_jar_name.jar
```

Comment: No, Its not in a jar.