# ProGuard on Android + reflection = NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, android, reflection, libgdx, proguard

Me name is Matthew and i have some trouble with reflection on Android after i use ProGuard.

I'm writing game in libgdx and I need to dynamically get String, I have something like this:

```
package com.PACKAGE;

    public class CLASS extends ANOTHER_CLASS{

        (...)

    private static void load(String fieldName) {
        Field field;
        String fileName;
        try {
            field = SOME_CLASS.class.getField(fieldName);
            fileName = (String) field.get(null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

         SOME_CLASS.SOME_METHOD.load(fileName);

    }

(...)

    private STH get(String fieldName) {
        Field field;
        String fileName;
        try {
            field = SOME_CLASS.class.getField(fieldName);
            fileName = (String) field.get(null);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

         return SOME_CLASS.SOME_METHOD.get(fileName);

    }

(...)

}
```

After I export release apk (compile fine) and run game, I get NoSuchFieldException:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: FIELD_NAME

What I need to add in `proguard-project.txt` to handle this? This is not working, I have no clue what to do.

```
-keepclassmembers class com.PACKAGE.CLASS { 
    String fileName;
}
```

class looks like:

```
package com.ANOTHER_PACKAGE;
public class SOME_CLASS {
    public static final String fieldName1 = "string I want";
    public static final String fieldName2 = "string I want";
    public static final String fieldName3 = "string I want";
}
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Selvin, the answer was

```
-keepclassmembers class ANOTHER_PACKAGE.SOME_CLASS { 
    public static final <fields>; 
}
```

in `project-proguard.txt`. Now it works perfectly :)

Comment: first why do you need a reflection for this. second, shouldn't it be `-keepclassmembers class com.PACKAGE.SOME_CLASS`

Comment: I need reflection to avoid write bunch of code, but maybe it was not a good idea. SOME_CLASS is in another package and there is more String fields I need to get, so I need to write all of them which it could be used via reflection?

-keepclassmembers class com.ANOTHER_PACKAGE.CLASS { 
   String fileName1;
   String fileName2;
   String fileName3;
}

Comment: so SOME_CLASS is from libgdx ? does fileName is static? do you know that `field.get(null)` is for static members? (i know that the error is not here but) you need to pass instance of SOME_CLASS instead null to get the non static field ...

Comment: Not from, but I use it in "core" section when you write in clean Java, not in "Android" section.

Yes all String I try get are static.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your proguard.cnf file

```
-keep public class * extends com.yoursite.android.yourappname.YourClassName

-keepclassmembers class * extends com.yoursite.android.yourappname.YourClassName{
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

Ref: [Proguard and reflection in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447145/proguard-and-reflection-in-android)