# Proguard: Keep classes in a certain package

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I have some classes which are used via reflection. It appears ProGuard is removing these when I build for release.

Is there any way to specify that all the classes in a particular package (as opposed to the specific class names) to not be removed when ProGuard runs. As a note, obfuscation is wanted. As another note, all these classes extend a single class which is present.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the solution mentioned [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447145/proguard-and-reflection-in-android) ?

Comment: I was looking at that but didn't understand. On one hand the first example says how to avoid obfuscating a class, the second example is talking about not obfuscating a specific method. So this isn't the same as my case. I want the classes included in the build and obfuscated.

Comment: well, classes with reflection shouldn't be obfuscated to make it works. so you can just apply "-keep class your-package" on your classes that are using reflection.

Comment: Oooohhh! Excellent point @baskara You're completely correct.

Answer (score 6):

Using     `-keep class com.yourpackage.name.** { *; }`  works well in my case. It essentially uses the wildcard to keep all classes belonging to that package. Also note the `*;` is required.

Also, to help debug your issue, you should check the generated `seeds.txt`, if the class is included then its kept.

Moreover it could be another issue like using public static inner classes or so. The best way to debug would be to decompile the minified apk using dex2jar and JD-GUI and manually skim through the code to see what's being stripped or kept. Don't forget to -dontdeobfuscate before.

Comment: This does keep the classes in the build, however they are not being obfuscated (as determined via inspection of mapping.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add this line in your `proguard-rules.pro` file?

```
-keep class com.company.application.PackagePrefix* 
{
*;
}
```

If you don't want to use package prefix you can use `**` instead.

Hope it helps.